# Convert string Jan to January, Feb to February, Mar to March etc

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I would like to be able to convert the string value Jan to January, Feb to February etc but I don't know how.

I have a table, populated some how, with the months, which looks like

```
                    Jan          Jul           Oct
Food                456          456           654
Drink               84516        54123         54213
Something           1            1             1
```

I am writing a report, which references the value of the cell (of the months). EG, Jan in the table in the cell above is in A2, then my function looks like

```
=CONCATENATE(A2, " and some content")
```

This works as expected, but, I'd rather it show the value January instead of Jan

I tried using `Month()` within the concatenation but it appears to want to take an integer.

I tried `TEXT(A2,"mmmm")` within the concatenation  but the value remains as `Jan`

How can I achieve this with no VBa?

Answer (score 0):

This does it

```
TEXT(DATE(2000,MONTH(A2&"-1"+0),1),"mmmm")
```

It simply converts the month to a number, and then uses that to create a new Date, and then uses Text to format it as desired.